# Como verificar a ocorrencia de uma string numa linha e pegar x caracteres a sua esquerda e y a direita?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Estou com um problema numa consulta MySQL e procuro ajuda.
Suponhamos que eu tenha muitas linhas na coluna PROCESSOS e uma delas é assim:

```
IBAMAPROCUR: DF00025372 ADRIANA MAIA VENTURINIAPDO: JOSE DOS
```

Eu quero verificar se existe os caractares 25372 nessa linha, se existir, quero pegar 10 caracteres antes do local e 10 depois. E verificar se nesse intervalo existe a sigla DF. Se existir, mostra a linha. Desta forma eu teria certeza de que se trata de um numero de OAB de Advogado. Alguém me daria uma ajuda para montar um `select` para isso?

Comment: Como é o conteúdo da coluna `PROCESSOS`? Do jeito que você está descrevendo o problema, e considerando como a solução do @Pasch não te atende, eu acho que você precisa primeiro normalizar o seu dado, em uma passada _offline_, para um modelo relacional; depois que isso estiver pronto, a solução do seu problema provavelmente será bem simples.

Comment: Eh, foi oq fiz... Achei que havia uma forma de fazer diretamente na query pois ficaria, acho eu, mais rápido devido aos algoritmos de busca selecionada que o SQL integra. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Um select comum com where não serve pra você?

SELECT Nome, Processos
FROM (Tabela)
WHERE Processos LIKE '%df%' AND Processos LIKE '%25372%'

Comment: Nao amigo, pois isso pegaria dados da linha linha inteira e ela pode ser beeem grande. Dai daria falso verdadeiro. Essa linha pode ter muitos numeros , muitas siglas... dai tem risco de dar verdadeiro mesmo nao sendo oq procuro. Tem que ser num intervalo: xxxxxx25372xxxxxxx
Se algum desses X for DF então tah certo

Comment: O número é sempre esse (25372)? E o número de caracteres até o DF é sempre esse? Se sim, dá pra usar underline. Tipo: SELECT Nome, Processos FROM Table WHERE Processos LIKE '_____________DF___25372%'. Os underlines são substitutos para qualquer caracter que venha no lugar dele. Desse jeito deve funcionar.

Comment: Meu velho, blza? O problema eh que são milhares de oabs... E as siglas são de todos os estados. A linha pode ter o conteúdo de varias paginas de PDF convertidos ou 100 caracteres. A OAB e sigla não seguem um padrão de posição nessa linga. Mês sempre que o numero for encontrado e existir a sigla próximo do numero então a chance de ser a OAB q to procurando aumenta infinitamente. Não consigo montar o comando. O programa eh java se,  e os dados pra pesquisa são passados por parâmetro. Dai eu preciso, se nessa linha tiver o numero e perto dele tiver a sigla retorne verdade. Entendeu? Obriga

Comment: Eu estou atualmente fazendo um like com o numero, dai com a resposta eu filtro pelo java, mas são milhões de linhas e.  milhares de oabs, dai to tentando melhorar o desempenho no processamento e essa query eu acho q seria minha solução.

Comment: @HadsonMarceloGomes Cara, aí fica bem complicado mesmo. O que sugeri funcionaria bem se o número sempre aparecesse no mesmo lugar. Mas o número é sempre esse 25372? Vou ver se encontro alguma outra forma de procurar ele em qualquer pedaço de uma coluna. E outra pergunta: é melhor primeiro procurar o número linha e, caso existe, verificar depois se existe a sigla. Correto?

Comment: Blza? Então, são centenas de milhares de números... Sim eh melhor procurar pelo numero primeiro mas dois select não afetaria o desempenho? Vlw

Comment: @HadsonMarceloGomes Bom, deve dar pra fazer com apenas um select. Se tiver alguma novidade, por favor, avisa aqui.